# Why is the output 'undefined' when run in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
const fruits = {
    apple: '',
    mango: '',
    peach: '',
    banana: '',
    pineapple: '',
    strawberry: '',

    getFruit(name) {
        return this.name;
    },
};

let name = 'apple';

var callFunc = fruits.getFruit(name);

console.log(callFunc);
```

Comment: Because `this` doesn't have a `name` property. Did you mean `this[name]`?

Answer (score 1):

`.name` refers to a member that's called name. Since you have no such member, `undefined` is returned. If you want to refer to a dynamic member, you can use the `[]` operator:

```js
const fruits = {
    apple: '',
    mango: '',
    peach: '',
    banana: '',
    pineapple: '',
    strawberry: '',

    getFruit(name) {
        return this[name]; // Here!
    },
};
```

Comment: Yes, I got it, I should be using this[name]. I am new to coding and really appreciate your reply. Thank you very much.